# Loop Solver over multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, solver

first time to StackOverflow and first time using Excel's VBA function.

I have a large spreadsheet that I would like to loop solver through (with this solver rows 523-1040), I've created a macro for the solver for the first row(523), but I have no idea how to get it to move down each row and constantly update the cells until it has gone through all the rows I need it to.

I would also like it to accept the answer, keep the answers and continue on...I think I may have that part of the code right.

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$R$523", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$D$523:$G$523" _
    , Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$523", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="15"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$523", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$523", Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$523", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="15"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$523", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$523", Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$523", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="15"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$523", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$523", Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$523", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="79"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$523", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$523", Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$523", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1500"
SolverOk SetCell:="$R$523", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$D$523:$G$523" _
    , Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
SolverOk SetCell:="$R$523", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$D$523:$G$523" _
    , Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
SolverSolve (True)

SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1


    The first four columns all get updated to effect the last column
    D   E   F   G   H   I       Q        R
    15  15  15  79  40  1115    317.69  1182727
    15  15  15  79  40  1699    390.06  2195098
    15  15  15  79  40  2720    491.56  4396517
    15  15  15  79  40  980     293.88  927830
    15  15  15  79  40  1653    379.15  1995816
    15  15  15  79  40  2889    494.67  4415459
    15  15  15  79  40  946     305.62  1036973
    15  15  15  79  40  1488    377.78  1976177
    15  15  15  79  40  2466    482.44  4126386
    15  15  15  79  40  437     223.64  345827
    15  15  15  79  40  450     242.50  427209
    15  15  15  79  40  1827    397.96  2315281
    15  15  15  79  40  456     219.01  335659
    15  15  15  79  40  432     232.34  387467
    15  15  15  79  40  1846    400.01  2332909
    15  15  15  79  40  680     254.58  582603
    15  15  15  79  40  1194    337.16  1365269
    15  15  15  79  40  2129    441.61  3152341
    15  15  15  79  40  734     252.43  576332
```

Comment: In addition to Ryan's code, adding SolverReset as such:

    SolverReset
    
    Dim startingRow As Long
    Dim endingrow   As Long
    Dim i           As Long
    startingRow = 543
    endingrow = 643
    
    

    For i = startingRow To endingrow
    SolverReset

Helped fix the code! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you need a loop.

Wasn't able to test this, but you should be able to concatenate strings together for the formula in the solver portions of the code. Basically you want the row to be dynamic, so you loop over a set of numbers (523 through 1040) and add that to your formula each time.

```
Sub SolverTest()
    Dim startingRow As Long
    Dim endingrow   As Long
    Dim i           As Long
    startingRow = 523
    endingrow = 1040

    For i = startingRow To endingrow
        SolverOk SetCell:="$R$" & i, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$D$" & i & " :$G$" & i _
        , Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="15"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$" & i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$" & i, Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="15"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$" & i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$" & i, Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="15"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$" & i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$" & i, Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="79"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$" & i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="1"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$" & i, Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$I$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1500"
        SolverOk SetCell:="$R$" & i, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$D$" & i & ":$G$" & i _
            , Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
        SolverOk SetCell:="$R$" & i, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$D$" & i & ":$G$" & i _
            , Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
    Next
    SolverSolve (True)
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much for responding, honestly not sure if that works or not though, Excel is now stuck at "setting up problem.."

Comment: Might take awhile! It's *might* take 500 times longer than it did for one row.

Comment: I got it working! Added "ServerReset" after "For i = startingRow To endingrow"

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark this as Accepted if this helped.